# how to implement open id in asp.net application in easy way

Tags: asp.net, security, session, openid

My asp.net application is still in development phase,is it possible to implement OPEN ID in my application?.I am new to asp.net kindly guide me how to implement open id.What are the necessary parameters i should keep in mind to improve security of my web application.Should i implement session in my project?

Answer (score 0):

The open source project [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) is a fantastic place to get started with integrating OpenID (and other, more up-to-date open web protocols such as OAuth 2.0) into your ASP.NET project.

They have tons of [great documentation and example projects](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/templatesgettingstarted/) that should be able to get you started quickly.